# Why am I receiving random null field values on my influx queries?

Tags: influxdb

I have a production application in which I am using a nodejs client to query the last point of a measurement every second. A separate client is writing a point to the measurement on a 1 second interval as well. After a few minutes, I **occasionally start receiving null values for random fields**. Some fields have data and others are null.

If I re-query for that exact same point a second later, all the values are there. I have also outputted the data to a csv file, and all the data is there as well.

I have recreated the issue on a standalone example. The issue occurs no matter if I use the npm influx library or make the http requests myself. The more frequent the requests are sent, the more frequent I get points containing null values. With the below example, if I run several instances of this app simultaneously, then many points will contain null values.

Is it possible that I am reading the point before influx has written all field values?
Any help is appreciated.

I'm using **influx v 1.8.2** and have recreated the issue on **ubuntu** and **windows**.

Code to recreate:

```
const { InfluxDB } = require("influx");

const influx = new InfluxDB({
  host: "localhost",
  database: "testDb",
});

const createDb = async () => {
  await influx.createDatabase("testDb");
};

const read = async () => {
  const res = await influx.query(`
  select * from livedata
  ORDER BY time desc
  limit 1
`);

 console.log(res[0]);

};

const write = async () => {
  await influx.writeMeasurement("livedata", [
    {
      tags: {
        id: "site",
      },
      fields: {
        site1: Math.random() * 1000,
        site2: Math.random() * 1000,
        site3: Math.random() * 1000,
        site4: Math.random() * 1000,
        site5: Math.random() * 1000,
        site6: Math.random() * 1000,
        site7: Math.random() * 1000,
        site8: Math.random() * 1000,
      },
    },
  ]);
};

createDb();

setInterval(() => {
  write();
  read();
}, 300);
```

Example output:

```
  [
    '2021-01-07T21:40:11.4031559Z',
    'site',
    830.4042230769617,
    522.1830877694142,
    698.8789904008146,
    678.305459618109,
    118.82269436309988,
    631.6295948279627,
    376.3112870744887,
    830.4872612882643
  ]
]
[
  [
    '2021-01-07T21:40:11.7034901Z',
    'site',
    null,
    null,
    null,
    65.3968316403697,
    680.7946463560837,
    330.7338852317838,
    872.7936919556367,
    145.03057994702618
  ]
]
[
  [
    '2021-01-07T21:40:12.0036893Z',
    'site',
    901.031149970251,
    501.1825877093237,
    99.38758592260699,
    78.79549874505165,
    403.8558500935323,
    545.085784401504,
    969.637642068842,
    51.657735620841194
  ]
]
```

Comment: I just ran into this today, you are not alone :)